# Query pl/sql record type in a simple sql

Tags: sql, plsql, record

I have a function in a package and it returns a user-defined record.

The record looks like:

```
type MyRecord is record (
    id varchar(15),
    start_date date
);
```

i want to call my function in a sql query. i tried this:

```
select id, start_date from (select mypackage.myfunc() from dual);
```

But it doesn't work. The main question is how can i call a stored function from a simple sql query. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i've found the answer:

```
select * from table(mypackage.myfunc());
```